# Regex: How can I find those html files with links that are not identical in different places?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have this link at the starting html page:

`<link rel="canonical" href="https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/experiencing-the-faith-shed-in-an-astral-moment.html" />`

also I have another link on the middle of the file:

`<a href="https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/experiencing-the-faith-shed-in-an-astral-moment.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_en.jpg" title="en" alt="en" width="28" height="19" /></a>`

You see that there are the same links, but in different contexts and places. Compare it.

But how can I find those html files with links that are not identical in those different places?

Suppose the first link will be: `<link rel="canonical" href="https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/eyes-accustomed-to-seeing-the-unseen.html" />` in this case are not identical those too, so regex should find that file that contains different links.

How can I do this with Regex?

Comment: That's not very clear. You want to find files where the `href` in the `<link` tag is **not** present in the whole html files? Is that correct?

Comment: How about: `<link .*?href=("[^"]+").*?(?:href=(?!\1).)+`

Comment: No no, IT is not about href or link. Is about the name of link. For example `https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/THIS-PAGE.com` and `https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/NOT-THIS-PAGE.com`

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion? It matches only when the `href` url in `<link` tag doesn't appear elsewhere in the file. If this is not what you want please, edit your question and add some examples that should match and some that shouldn't.

Comment: @Toto oh, yes, very sorry. WORKS. I've missed to check `. matches newline`, because you didn't mention about `. matches newline` . Works: snipboard.io/pAJgH5.jpg Please put is as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Toto:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `<link .*?href=("[^"]+").*?(?:href=(?!\1).)+`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** *[.] matches newsline*
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>